# Rename a string adding a number if it already exist in a column VBA

Tags: vba

I have a column of headers that sometimes contains duplicates. I want to setup code that will find these duplicate headers and add a number to the end to make them all unique.

For example, If "Proprietorship Concern" were to appear twice I would want the first changed to "Proprietorship Concern1" and the second to "Proprietorship Concern2". If there is no duplicate of a header, I do not want any numbers attached to the end of it.

Each header will be followed by a "header" called "Address". I need to rename these to copy the value of the above field with "Address" added onto the end. For example, the "Address" in the field below "Subject Info" would become "Subject Info Address".

You can see what I am trying to achieve from the example data below.

[image: Example using test data]

This will be running on a file with over 1000 records and as I am quite new to VBA I am looking for some help with the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Headers exist in column "A", Footers in column "B" and the table is on continuous rows.

Comment: What logic depicts 'ADDRESS' going to 'SUBJECT INFORMATION ADDRESS' and likewise for the 'ADDRESS' under 'PROPRIETORSHIP CONCERN'

Comment: Will there always be an address following a header and will the following address always belong to the header above it?

Comment: Address will always follow "Subject Info" or Proprietorship Concern. Following address will always belong to the header above it

Comment: Do you want the first of each header to end in 1 or without a number at the end?

Comment: Numerals to be added only if there are multiple occurrence of text

Comment: @Tom  ADDRESS Alway follows from the information above, viz. Address in Row 2 pertains to subject information, similarly address in row 4 pertains to first proprietorship concern and Address in row 6 pertains to proprietorship concern above it. This is how data is collected.

Comment: You've tagged the question with VBA. Please, post the code you've tried and where are you stuck

Comment: If you're only doing it once you could use a formula in column `C`.  Enter in `C2` and drag down: `=IF($A2="ADDRESS",$A2 & " " &  $C1,$A2 & IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$7,$A2)>1,COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,$A2),""))`

Comment: This need to be run on a whole list of excel files (>1000), that's why was banking on VBA. @foxfire novice here in VBA, so was banking on the community to help me with code which i can build upon.

Answer (score 1):

The code below should do everything you are looking for.

As this solution uses a dictionary to store the headers you will not have to search through the entire column for matches every other line unlike Tom's solution which should leave it a lot faster.

When it comes to `ADDRESS` fields it simply copies the header above and adds `ADDRESS` to the end of it as the above field will have been formatted already and this again prevents you having to needlessly check and compare headers.

```
Public Sub renameHeaders()

    Dim headerRange As Range
    Dim headerCell As Range
    Dim headerValue As String
    Dim headerDict As Object
    Set headerDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    'CHANGE SHEET1 NAME HERE TO YOUR SHEET
    With Sheets("Sheet1") 'Get all headers
        Set headerRange = .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    End With

    For Each headerCell In headerRange.Cells 'Check each header
        headerValue = headerCell.Value
        If headerValue = "ADDRESS" Then 'If "Address" simply add address to above value
            headerCell.Value = headerCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value & " ADDRESS"
        Else
            If headerDict.exists(headerValue) Then
                'If header seen before start adding numbers
                If IsNumeric(headerDict(headerValue)) Then
                    headerDict(headerValue) = headerDict(headerValue) + 1
                Else
                    headerDict(headerValue).Value = headerValue & "1"
                    headerDict(headerValue).Offset(1, 0).Value = headerValue & "1 ADDRESS"
                    headerDict(headerValue) = 2
                End If
                headerCell.Value = headerValue & headerDict(headerValue)
            Else
                'If not already seen leave header as is and add to dict
                headerDict.Add headerValue, headerCell
            End If
        End If
    Next headerCell

End Sub
```

[image: Spreahsheet Example]

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following. Will need to be updated with your input and output

```
Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim tmpStr As String
    Dim concat As Boolean
    Dim i As Long

    ' Update with your input range
    With ActiveSheet
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1))
    End With

    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        tmpStr = vbNullString
        concat = (i Mod 2 = 0)

        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, rng(i - 1, 1).Value2) > 1 Then
            tmpStr = IIf(concat, rng(i - 1, 1).Value2, rng(i, 1).Value2) & _
                     WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(rng.Cells(1), rng(i, 1)), IIf(concat, rng(i - 1, 1).Value2, rng(i, 1).Value2)) & _
                     IIf(i Mod 2 = 0, " " & rng(i, 1).Value2, vbNullString)
        Else
            tmpStr = IIf(concat, rng(i - 1, 1).Value2, rng(i, 1).Value2) & IIf(concat, " " & rng(i, 1).Value2, vbNullString)
        End If

        ' Update with where you want data to be output to
        rng(i, 1).Offset(0, 4).Value2 = tmpStr
        rng(i, 1).Offset(0, 5).Value2 = rng(i, 2).Value2
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]